# "Not a bad little haul for one night" meaning

Tags: spoken-english

> "It is you! If they find out who they've got --! They're Snatchers, they're only looking for truants to sell for gold --"
>
> "**Not a bad little haul for one night**," Greyback was saying, ... ...
>
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows</sub>

I've searched the phrase "[Not a bad little haul](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1280&bih=697&ei=Gy7uXaWeHY_v-QaWzYSYAg&q=not%20a%20bad%20little%20haul&oq=not%20a%20bad%20little%20haul&gs_l=psy-ab.3..33i160.2112.3630..4626...0.0..0.649.4351.2-2j2j3j3......0....1..gws-wiz.8KT7t5J9fNY&ved=0ahUKEwjll6u4uajmAhWPd94KHZYmASMQ4dUDCAo&uact=5)" and got lots of hits. It seems a quite common phrase, but none of them addressed what it means. What does it mean truly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *haul* is the amount caught, fishing in a net, or more generally, the amount taken in another operation, such as salvage, or theft.

*not a bad (little)* is an example of [litotes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Litotes), and means *a good amount*.

So a praphrase would be something like *We've captured quite a good number of truants, maybe better than the average for one night*.